# Trouble with usb cable weight

Tags: laptop, usb

I use a laptop as a PC, I just let it there with all my things plugged on, but I have a problem with the weight of my USB cables. I bought one of those supports that go under the laptop and have a cooler, it is powered with an USB cable that has a USB port on it, but if I use the port that the USB cable has the weight of it damages the port on my laptop, what should I do?

Comment: Maybe redesign your surroundings:  USB RF plug for Keyboard and Mouse, Networked Printer (not even attached), Wireless network (no Ethernet cable).  So then what is left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those cooling stations are very useful for certain laptops that generate sunstantial heat. We used to have one a while go before moving to a cooler-ultra-book.

The easy thing to do to avoid a USB port have support too much weight is to move the weight to something that is sitting on the table. For this I recommend a USB hub. Some hubs are rather small and light for portability but in your case, particularly if you have a number of devices, you can get a larger *powered* USB hub. This allows ports to keep supplying more power than having to distribute the output of one port onto several. Some devices like external disks that don't have their own power supply, only work with a powered USB hub.

If you notice that only one or two devices are causing strain on the port, you could get 1 or 2 extension cables to place those devices on the table which will reduce stress on the USB port.